# Incrementing with for in while loop results in 0

Tags: php, increment

Why won't $i count up one each time with the following code?

```
<?php if(get_field('staff_member')) { ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <?php while(has_sub_field('staff_member')) 
        {
        for($i = 0; $i <= 1;  $i++)
        echo '<div class="span3 mobile_width' . $i . '"> 

    .....etc...
}
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

The output has 4 items and they all return with the the class mobile_width0.

And it also outputs 2 of each item.

Comment: Because `$i` is being reset to `0` on each of the four iterations of the `while()` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are resetting it to 0 each time. You don't need `for` loop, that's why you had double output. You can do it like this:

```
<?php $i = 0; 
    while(has_sub_field('staff_member')) {
        echo '<div class="span3 mobile_width' . $i . '">';
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++)
```

`<` instead of `<=`

Answer (score 0):

because your resetting "i" to 0 in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Each time your while cicle iterates, `$i` gets reset to 0 and in this line `for($i = 0; $i <= 1;  $i++)` you are saying that `$i` just can take 0 and 1 values